# Debounce with ngMouseover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this HTML div which uses the `ngMouseover` directive to get some data from the api via a function as follows:

**Markup:**

```
<div ng-mouseover="getData()">
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.getData = function() {
    //get data from api
}
```

Is there any way in which I can add a delay to the `ngMouseover` directive such that it is fired only after the cursor has stayed for a few seconds on the div? Just like it is with `debounce` in `ngModelOptions`.

Comment: I don't think it exists in Angular (but it's a really good idea!). I found [this](https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce), but I think it sucks to add a dependency just for that

Comment: I think i am going to use some convoluted way with $timeout or something. :(

Comment: debounce uses timeout ^^. If it's not built in, do it yourself ;)

Comment: i love underscore/lodash, and they are super helpful for a lot of other reasons. they both also have debounce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`: If the mouse enters the element and doesn't leave for at least 2 seconds, then evaluate.

```
<div debounce-mouseover="getData()" stay-at-least="2"></div>
```

And the directive `debounceMouseover` is:

```
template: "<div ng-mouseenter="onEnter()" ng-mouseleave="onLeave()">",

link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  var stayAtLeast = attrs.stayAtLeast;
  var timer;

  scope.onEnter = function() {
    timer = $timeout(function() {
      scope.$eval(attrs.debounceMouseover);
    }, stayAtLeast);
  };

  scope.onLeave = function() {
    $timeout.cancel(timer);
  };
}
```

(that's the generic idea, actual implementation is left to you, if you need help let me know)